# Selecting Capacitor to reduce AC ripple from Car Alternator - LED Indicators only work when Engine Off

Tags: led, automotive, alternator

My neighbour has recently installed some aftermarket LED indicators, when the engine is switched off the units work as expected, switching from white headlight mode, to blinking yellow mode.

When the engine is running the units become erratic and do not behave as expected. I suspect interference from the alternator is confusing the LED driver circuit.

What capacitor could I add and where in the circuit to help reduce the noise?

Much Appreciated

Comment: What circuit did you attach them to?  What else is on that circuit?  12V system?  Did you use automotive rated components for the drivers and LEDs?

Comment: its an automotive LED indicator kit - so I assume so. The driver unit has the following connections 12V, GND & Signal for the turn indicator - it was connected in place of where the normal incandescent indicator bulb would go with an extra lead run to 12V on the battery post.

Comment: Power should probably be taken from the fuse box. Semiconductors are notorious for shorting when they fail. Fuse protection is important. Keep in mind that the battery charges at ~14.5 V so make sure anything you connect is okay with that.